# Django Model.create won't save to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-generic-views, django-managers

I'm trying to create an instance of a model (Transaction) from a view's `post` method but it's not saving to the database, but to my surprise is that, after "creating the object" and it not saving, i can pass it to my context dict and use its values, some which are autogenerated but still wont save :(.

I've tried bumping up the line tjat creates that instance to the first line in the method but still wont work. (Django Admin works though)

```py
from django.views import generic
...
from arctic.core.models import Transaction  # Get transaction model

class MyView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = "temps/page.html"
    model = Application
    context_object_name = "object_name"
    slug_field = 'uuid_id'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'obj_id'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check if object is accepted
        if not self.get_object().accepted or self.get_object().acknowledged:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

        # Else, continue
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        poll_url = "http://test-link.com/"
        trans = Transaction.objects.create(poll_url=poll_url)
```

It just wont save. PS: I didnt override any of the models's methods(s)

**UPDATE**
Here are the variables from the traceback i induced"

```py
context 
{}  

kwargs  
{'obj_id': UUID('f4228ebf-9b26-4e95-85b1-7570d92458c4')}  

poll_url    
'https://www.test-link.com/'  

request 
<WSGIRequest: POST '/acknowledge-acceptance-and-register/f4228ebf-9b26-4e95-85b1-7570d92458c4/'>  

self    
<arctic.applications.views.MyView object at 0x000002CAA9BB1A58>  

trans
<Transaction: Transaction object (115)>
```

What I've discovered from this is that the `pk`/`id` default incremental primary key by django keeps incrementing..implying its reaching the database but then not saving :(, even in Django-admin, the `pk` is incrementing, that is when i repeat this request, it increments by 1, but does not save, but then add using django admin, it saves with a `pk` or `id` +2 (skipping one as if it has been saved)

Comment: can you update your code to show where you are importing `Transaction` and `generic` from?

Comment: Edited as suggested

Comment: Have you tried adding `trans.save()` at the end of your POST fuction?

Comment: Yes i did. Tried both: `Transaction(**args).save()` and `Transaction.objects.create(**kwargs)`